# How to connect Google Cloud Library for Datastore to the App Engine development server?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

We are planning the migration of an internal app running on Google App Engine Standard Environment for Java 8 from the now superseded [App Engine APIs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/datastore/#connecting_to_datastore_name_short_with_app_engine) to the recommended client library for [Cloud Firestore in Datastore Mode](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/using-cloud-datastore), also in order to enable porting to other execution environments.

Besides a host of issues with missing IN/OR query operators, we are also struggling with the setup for local testing: according to [Using the Java 8 Local Development Server](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/tools/using-local-server#datastore)

> The development web server simulates Datastore using a local
>   file-backed Datastore on your computer. The Datastore is named
>   local_db.bin, and it is created in your application's WAR directory,
>   in the WEB-INF /appengine-generated/ directory.

but we have no clue about how to connect Google Cloud Client Library for Datastore to the local emulator.

Defining default credentials with

```sh
gcloud auth application-default login
```

or setting the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable after obtaining the credentials for the service account with something like

```sh
gcloud iam service-accounts keys create key.json \
    --iam-account=project-id@appspot.gserviceaccount.com
```

as suggested elsewhere, just results in the client library connecting to the actual cloud server, rather than to the local emulator, as per the [ADC](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#finding_credentials_automatically) policy.

I'd expect the development server to automatically provide connection hints to the client library, but that's apparently not the case.

Any suggestion for setting up a local testing environment, taking into account that we can't just migrate to the standalone [Datastore Emulator](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/tools/datastore-emulator), as we need other services currently provided only by the App Engine development server (e.g. email submission)?

---

**Edit** / After further tinkering we are working around the issue by using both the Local Development Server and the standalone Datastore Emulator as:

```
gcloud beta emulators datastore start \
  —project=project-id \
  --host-port=localhost:8081 \
  --data-dir=target/war

DATASTORE_EMULATOR_HOST=localhost:8081 java_dev_appserver.sh \
 --port=8080 \
 target/war
```

However, the process is quite cumbersome and difficult to automate: what we are looking for is a way to automatically connect Google Client Library to the Datastore Emulator managed by the Java 8 Local Development Server when launching the app with something like the [App Engine Maven plugin](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/app-maven-plugin), e.g. `mvn appengine:run`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [GitHub issue](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-java/issues/1328#issuecomment-255323558) was closed with the confirmation that the Datastore Client Library is not compatible with the local Web Server Datastore Emulator.

I actually tried it, to see if was possible to force a connection to the local Web Server. The code below sets a custom builder with the desired host configuration:

```
DatastoreOptions.Builder builder = DatastoreOptions.newBuilder();
builder.setHost("http://localhost:8080");
builder.setProjectId("<PROJECT_ID>");

Datastore ds = builder.build().getService();

Key key = ds.newKeyFactory().setKind("MyEntity").newKey("mykey");
Entity entity = Entity.newBuilder(key).set("p1", "Hello World!").build();

entity = ds.put(entity);
System.out.println(entity);

entity = ds.get(key);
System.out.println(entity);
```

After running the local Web Server I noticed a connection was indeed possible, however the Datastore Client Library returned the following error when trying to store new entities:

```
[INFO] GCLOUD: com.google.cloud.datastore.DatastoreException: Non-protobuf error: <html><head><title>Error 404</title></head>|<body><h2>Error 404</h2></body>|</html>. HTTP status code was 404.
```

With the following output by the Web Server:

```
Oct 02, 2019 3:05:59 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.jetty9.LocalResourceFileServlet doGet
WARNING: No file found for: /v1/projects/<PROJECT_ID>:commit
```

I believe this adds to the confirmation that the new library is just not compatible to the old emulator.

The workaround you found is probably the best solution while you work/wait on the full migration to the Datastore mode Emulator.

Comment: Spot on… I opened  an [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/141869012) on the public Google issue tracker, FWIW